# Как получить конкретное значение JSON

Tags: java, json

у меня есть json файл

```
{
  "stations": {
    "11": [
      "Савёловская",
      "Петровский парк",
      "ЦСКА",
      "Хорошёвская",
      "Шелепиха",
      "Деловой центр",
      "Народное Ополчение",
      "Мнёвники"
    ],
    "11A": [
      "Каховская",
      "Варшавская",
      "Каширская"
    ],
    "12": [
      "Битцевский парк",
      "Лесопарковая",
      "Улица Старокачаловская",
      "Улица Скобелевская",
      "Бульвар адмирала Ушакова",
      "Улица Горчакова",
      "Бунинская Аллея"
    ],
```

там ещё много строк, поэтому решил эту небольшую часть показать.

мои подключённые библиотеки: json-simple и jsoup

по заданию мне нужно получить количество станций, а для этого их нужно достать

вот всё, что я пока смог сделать

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject a = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Юзер\\java_basics\\LearnJsoup\\jsoup\\src\\jsoupMetro\\WriteJson\\test.json"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Достаем весь объект `"stations"`, далее достаем массив по номеру линии `"11"`, далее достаем название станции по индексу `3`:

```java
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(...);
JSONObject stations = (JSONObject) json.get("stations");
JSONArray grayLine = (JSONArray) stations.get("11");
String myStation = (String) grayLine.get(3); // => "Хорошёвская"
```

Как просуммировать количество станций по всем линиям метро? Множество ключей всех линий метро можно получить так: `stations.keySet()`, и пройтись по всем ключам в цикле:

```java
int count = 0;
for (Object key : stations.keySet()) {
    JSONArray line = (JSONArray) stations.get(key);
    count += line.size();
}
System.out.println(count); # => 18
```

Comment: а как получить все станции. я понимаю, что циклом, но там везде разное количество станций

Comment: добавил в ответ как пройтись по всем линиям метро с помощью `stations.keySet()` и просуммировать количество всех станций

Comment: Нифига ты машина :)
спасибо огромное.